# How to edit /etc/hosts in Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-container-instances

I try to edit /etc/hosts through the echo IP Hostname >> /etc/hosts command, but it seems that ACI rewrites the file.
I've already tried putting it in dockerfile and also through the --command-line but none works.

Comment: To clarify, by "command-line" you mean the `--add-host` parameter as described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts)?

Comment: No. az container create --command-line "echo IP Hostname >> /etc/hosts".

Comment: I'm not really into Azure containers so I cannot give you a solution, but I'd like to point out that even with a local Docker installation your approach would not work, since the `/etc/hosts` file is managed by Docker for container networking purposes. Since in Azure you would deploy your container in a virtual network environment it is likely that this also applies in that context.
So you might want do dig a little deeper into how networking works with Azure, or find another way to add a static IP to your container (such as an environment variable).

Comment: I think it's the problem about the endpoint in Docker. The command overrides the endpoint so that the container instance terminate after running the command even if the command failed. You can use the `az container exec` to run the command when the container instance is in the running state.

Comment: Any more question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Docker, it will manage the `/etc/hosts` for you when you execute the Docker CLI [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts), see

**Managing /etc/hosts:**

> Your container will have lines in /etc/hosts which define the hostname
>   of the container itself as well as localhost and a few other common
>   things.

And for Azure Container Instance, specify a command line when you create a container instance to override the command line baked into the container image. This is similar to the `--entrypoint` command-line argument to `docker run`. The container instance would terminate after executing the command. For more details, see [Command line override](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/container-instances/container-instances-restart-policy.md#command-line-override).

I suggest you can make an interactive shell with the container instance through the CLI command `az container exec containerName --exec-command "/bin/sh"` if the image has the `/bin/sh` and the container instance has the public IP.

And if you have more confixed actions with the container, maybe [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/) is more appropriate for you.